# TextToSpeech Null Pointer Exception with Context

Tags: android, pointers, null, android-context

I'm attempting to create a TextToSpeech manager class.
I'm getting a Null Pointer Exception error when the class’s constructor is called.
 The TTS managing class accepts a single Context parameter.
The MainActivity class attempts to instantiate the object by calling

```
TTS_Manager tts = new TTS_Manager(this);
```

Logcat shows the TTS_Manager class’s constructor being called and then the NPE:

```
TextToSpeech ttsVoice = new TextToSpeech(context, this);
```

My take is that there is something wrong with the way the context is being handled.

```
package com.example.TTS01;

import android.content.Context;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.UtteranceProgressListener;

public class TTS_Manager implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener{
    TextToSpeech ttsVoice;

    public void TTS_Manager(Context context){
        //Null Pointer Exception thrown on next line
        TextToSpeech ttsVoice = new TextToSpeech(context, this);

        ttsVoice.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStart(String utteranceID) {
                            }

            @Override
            public void onDone(String utteranceID) {
                            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String utteranceID) {
                            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int i) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're leaking a partially constructed TTS_Manger in it's own constructor function by passing this to new TextToSpeech.  For example, the ttsVoice member will be null at this time.  Also:

```
TextToSpeech ttsVoice = new TextToSpeech(context, this);
```

Does not updated the member, but a local variable.

Avoid passing this in the constructor to other classes.